# How to find the partial derivative of a function with respecte to another mulitvariables function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Suppose we have $T=f(q_1,q_2,t)$,
I am trying to find the the following:
$$ \frac{\partial T}{\partial q}=??$$
provided that:
$$ q=q_1+bq_2$$ where b is constant.
Is it going to be:
$$ \frac{\partial T}{\partial q}=\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_1} \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial q}+\frac{\partial T}{\partial q_2} \frac{\partial q_2}{\partial q} ?$$
or something else, help me please.
I found some similar stuff [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989040/partial-derivative-of-multivariable-function-with-respect-to-another-function) and [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291376/differentiate-with-respect-to-a-function), but mine is slightly different.

Comment: I believe you're correct.

Comment: Any one who is sure to put an answer !!